# Can I speed up queries if I can narrow down the position in the table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-performance

This is a conceptual question that has been bothering me for a while, but I haven't found a good solution yet (I am not really a database ninja):

I need to find a specific row in a table that stores an identifier (along with some other stuff) in an XML column. This is done by a third party component and i cannot change that. That table is rather large, so parsing all those XMLs to find the identifier is pretty slow (I am using Postgres' built-in XML parser).
But I know that the row I am searching for is one of the *last few rows inserted*.

Is there any reasonable approach to speed up my query?

(I do have a timestamp column, but i doubt that ordering my entries would actually speed up my query.)

Edit:

**Database Table:**

- id (bigserial)
- sentdate (bigint)
- stanza (text) <-- contains message XML
- body (text)
- plus some non-relevant string columns

**XML example (shortened)**

```xml
<message id="my_unique_identifier" to="user@chat_server" type="groupchat" from="chat_room@chat_server">
  <body>Hello World!</body>
</message>
```

**My very basic query so far (that just does an xpath lookup)**

```sql
SELECT messages.* 
FROM messages 
WHERE ((xpath('/message/@id', stanza::XML))[1]::TEXT = 'my_unique_identifier') 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Even if you can't modify how the data is inserted, can you modify the table itself?  If you need to do this frequently, you might want to do a trigger or some kind of batch process to extract the value and store it in its own column.

Comment: Don't know how large is the table. Ordering .. no indexed column for example can be expensive. How many "last few rows"? You can then just do select a process in app if there's a big database performancie issue .. which is not 100% desired solution.

Comment: I can add columns or indexes to the table. I cannot tell the exact amount of "last few rows" since a few seconds may pass between the row being inserted and my application searching for it, where new rows could be created.

Comment: Is that always the same WHERE clause?

Comment: The identifier changes every time.

Comment: But the xpath condition does not?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name correct.

Comment: Hmm, if `stanz` was properly declared as `xml` you could create an index on the xpath expression, however the cast from `text` to `xml` does not seem to be immutable, so Postgres doesn't allow to create an index on that expression.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I don't know what considerations cause PostgreSQL to mark that as not immutable.  But if Zyndoras looks into it and decides those considerations don't apply to her, she can create a wrapper function declared to be immutable and build the index with that.

Comment: @jjanes: I was quite surprised as well that the cast to xml isn't immutable

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for one row and there is an index on `(timestamp)`, then the following will probably be faster:

```
select t.*
from t
where . . . 
order by timestamp desc
limit 1;
```

Because of the `order by`, Postgres will probably choose to scan the data in the index order.  However, there are no guarantees and Postgres may still decide to do all the parsing first and the sorting afterwards.

You *might* find a full text index helpful for what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

> (I do have a timestamp column, but i doubt that ordering my entries would actually speed up my query.)

Curious doubt to have, since it seems to be the whole point of the question.  Did you try it?  What is the name of that column? Is it indexed?  You show a column named 'sentdate', which seems promising by name, but it is described as bigint, not timestamp.  If your "id (bigserial)" is truly populated by a sequence, ordering by that could also work.

Are you absolutely certain the row will be found at all?  You could do.

```
SELECT ...
WHERE ((xpath('/message/@id', stanza::XML))[1]::TEXT = 'my_unique_identifier')
order by timestamp_column desc limit 1;
```

But if there are no rows meeting the condition, this will have catastrophic performance before returning zero rows.

You could get around that possibility with something like:

```
with t as (SELECT * from messages
    order by timestamp_column desc limit 100
)
select ... from t
    WHERE ((xpath('/message/@id', stanza::XML))[1]::TEXT = 'my_unique_identifier')
    order by timestamp_column desc limit 1;
```

That way it will give up if it doesn't find it in the "last" 100 rows.

Comment: I did try ordering my query first, but I did not notice any difference. Either Postgres decides to ignore my ordering, or it does perform the order but now the ordering costs about the same amount of time.

Comment: @Zyndoras we could tell if you show the EXPLAIN for the query, or better yet the EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS).